# Auto-centering elements when using Data Merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I'm using data merge to fill in data of a master template. I have a group of three placeholders: a circle (colors vary), a number on top of it, and variable-length text (a name) to the right. As placeholders, everything works correctly - but I need these elements centered horizontally as a group.

Because data merge is regenerated every time I update the document, I don't want to manually center these every time. Is there a way I can group them and automate centering?

Here's what it currently produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just make the icon group a anchored object that's part of your text. Then apply center to the paragraph where the text/anchor is.

If your icon is not anchored

- just group circle and text,
- cut said group,
- enter type tool in text and paste.

Comment: This puts me on the right direction - I've got things centering properly using this method, but the circle/number is too wide, leaving a large gap between it and the text. When I shrink it, the circle gets smaller. I'll need to play around with it.

Comment: I resized the circle/text individually before making the group and it all looks nice. I have too small of a space between then now... lol, but I can fix it

Comment: @helion3 you can use tracking to fix the gap